# retrieve SSH unique session ID

Tags: session, ssh, uniqueidentifier, openssh

I wonder if there is any way to retrieve, for both a server and a client connected through ssh (OpenSSH), some unique session identifier (let this be *USID*).

This would be used to restrict the execution of a specific (custom) software (let it be **a.exe**), so it can *only be executed through a specific ssh session*, even if other users (potentially root) have access to that executable:

- after a ssh session is opened from machine **C** (client) to machine **S** (server), machine **C** (which knows the *USID*) will update a record on machine **X** (a third-party server), letting it know that this *USID* is "safe".
- **a.exe** on machine **S** will check, when invoked, if the *USID* of the current session is "safe" (this information will be provided by **X**) and will halt execution if negative answer received.

The communication channels between **X** and **C**, **X** and **S** are secure, so the only issue here is retrieving that *USID* **without** having to write my own ssh client and/or server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't use a public key as your USID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me in a round about way, you are trying to re-implement kerberos. Seems to me that you want to GSSAPI secure the transport between client and server; so your client needs to authenticate to the server.

Typical way of doing this would be to 'kinit' to a prinicpal using a keytab, and then passing this credential to the server. Kerberos ensures that it's reasonably hard to fake.

that's probably going to be a little less brittle than the method that you describe above.

-Ace