# Give PAM the SSH session ID

Tags: session, ssh, pam

I'm trying to write a PAM module for SSH where a login is authorized by a third party. I want to send this third party the SSH session ID number so that the third party can be confident that they are only approving the login for a single SSH session. Does anyone know how to pass such information to PAM, or access this information from a PAM module?

Thanks!

NOTE: I don't believe this is a duplicate question as [retrieve SSH unique session ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232646/retrieve-ssh-unique-session-id#2232689), as my goal is not to restrict the user once they are authenticated. My goal is only to include approval from a third party in the authorization stack.

Comment: Anything new here? I also need a session id for a custom script. Any luck? I have tried to echo all env vars that start with "PAM", but there is no session id for ssh.